# Will an existing script of MonkeyRunner works if the screen layout changes?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

will an existing script of MonkeyRunner works if the screen layout changes ? e.g. screen toggles potrait to landscape mode, or , variation in screen size between multiple devices etc.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) has the abilities you mentioned. http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2014/11/culebra-cross-device-application-tests.html describes the steps to create a test taht could run on multiple devices.